# How to delete a values in the Json array in yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have Json array

```
{"dashboard_layout":[10,9]}
```

based on the `id` I have to delete the values from this array.

This is my function .and I added my view page also .Always going to alert(failed) part .Is something Wrong in this function

```
  public function actionDelete() {
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        $blockvalues = json_decode($model->others);
        foreach ($blockvalues as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $id) {
                unset($blockvalues[$key]);
                echo Json::encode([
                    'status' => true,
                ]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,
            'id'=>$id
        ]);
    }
}



    jQuery('body').on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
  var id=$(this).val();
    alert(id);
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data:{'id': id},
            url: '".Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("/dashboard-blocks/delete")."',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 
              alert('hii');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert('failed');
            }
        });
});
```

Note:
$model->others contain json {"dashboard_layout":[10,9]}

Comment: is the above the exact json that is retrieved from the database column `$model->others`

Comment: yes...$model->others have  json {"dashboard_layout":[10,9]}

Comment: change the `alert('failed')` to `alert(thrownError)` and see what messsage it prints.

Comment: Internal Server Error ...is showing in the alert when I put  alert(thrownError);

Comment: that means you are getting an error in the server side code for the action by checking the request inside the `console` and see what does the response show, it should show you the exact error that is occurring in the code

Comment: see my **EDIT 2** in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are using `json_decode('{"dashboard_layout":[10,9]}')` which will return

```
stdClass Object
(
    [dashboard_layout] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```

so you should iterate on

```
foreach ($blockvalues->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {
```

or use `yii\helpers\Json::decode('{"dashboard_layout":[10,9]}')` which will return an array

```
Array
(
    [dashboard_layout] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```

and then you should iterate on

```
foreach ($blockvalues['dashboard_layout'] as $key => $value) {
```

## `EDIT`

So your code should look like

```
 public function actionDelete() {
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        $blockvalues = json_decode($model->others);
        foreach ($blockvalues->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $id) {
                unset($blockvalues[$key]);
                echo Json::encode([
                    'status' => true,
                ]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,
            'id'=>$id
        ]);
    }
}
```

## `EDIT 2`

There was one thing missing that i didnt updated regarding your code, i figured out why the error was occurring, i had to change `unset($blockvalues[$key]);` to `unset($blockvalues->dashboard_layout[$key]);`.

Another thing is that looking at your code it looks like that you are trying to remove the selected `id` from the `dashboard_layout` index that is saved as json in the `UserPreferences` table's column `others`, so just unsetting the json array only wont help you as it is un-setting the **array index only** and you are not updating the array back to the table column.

If the above is true then you should add the following inside the `foreach` loop or inside the check

```
$model->others=json_encode($blockvalues);
$model->save();
```

your code will look like following after the update

```
public function actionDelete() {
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        $blockvalues = json_decode($model->others);
        foreach ($blockvalues->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $id) {
                unset($blockvalues->dashboard_layout[$key]);

                //save the new updated dashbooard_layouts values
                $model->others=json_encode($blockvalues);
                $model->save();

                echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
                    'status' => true,
                ]);
            }
        }



    } else {
        echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
            'status' => false,
            'id'=>$id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean like this

Comment: $blockvalues = yii\helpers\Json::decode($model->others);
            foreach ($blockvalues[$model->others] as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == $id) {
                   unset($blockvalues[$key]);

Comment: are you getting any errors when you say it is not working?

Comment: Ajax is failing

Comment: what exception are you getting please addd proper message for the error you are receiving

Comment: @muhammed I posted my view page..Its alaways displaying as ajax failed in alert

Comment: @muhammed its showing as undefined in my alert.And thank you for the response I got the answer I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionDelete() {
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        // check here if model is not null 
        $perferencesOther = json_decode($model->others);            

        if(!empty($perferencesOther) && isset($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout)) {
            $dashboardLayout = [];       
            foreach ($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {                    
                if($value != $id){
                    $dashboardLayout[] = $value;                      
                }
            } 

            $perferencesOther->dashboard_layout = $dashboardLayout;                
            // store updated preferencves in db
            $model->others = json_encode($perferencesOther); 
            $model->save();

            echo Json::encode([
                'status' => true,
                'value'=>$model->others
            ]);                
        }          
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,              
        ]);
    }
}
```

This works for me